# Using hamachi to access proxmox web-GUI

Tags: proxmox

I have a server with multiple network adaptors. I have installed proxmox and hamachi on that.

I want to be able to access the web GUI through hamachi. I am not able to port forward or have both the server and laptop on the same network. My server IP on hamachi is `25.54.34.60`.

I want to be able to access the web-GUI, which is accessible on `152.78.218.71:8006` from the hamachi IP. I have no idea how to do this. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Google translation of original post:

install hamachi and when accessing the web use

```
https://25.54.34.60:8006
```

don't forget to create a network in hamachi and in the root console put

```
hamachi join network_name password
```

this makes it join your network

---

Original post (with contents from other (now deleted) answer by same user added):

instala hamachi y al aceder a la web usa

```
https://25.54.34.60:8006
```

no olvide crear una red en hamachi 
y en la consola root poner

```
hamachi join nombre_de_la_red password
```

esto hace que se una a su red

Comment: He traducido tu respuesta con Google Translate. Por favor considere publicar en inglés aquí.